# How to override the cancel button in the UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar

I am currently using the following method to stop the cancel button item from showing up in the search bar. I have a custom `UIButton` that I would like to use instead.

The problem is that at the moment the built in cancel button is still showing up.

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    controller.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: are you adding search bar programaticaly or through XIB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide your cancel button using this

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *possibleButton in searchBar.subviews)
{  
    if ([possibleButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])  
    {  
        UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)possibleButton;  
        cancelButton.enabled = YES;  
        break;
    }    
}
```

one go through this link [UISearchBar disable auto disable of cancel button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348351/uisearchbar-disable-auto-disable-of-cancel-button)

Answer (score 0):

`Swift` **4.2, 4.0+** of [Rajneesh071](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1369972/rajneesh071) answer

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
}
```